# How to specify a search radius for Reverse Geocode endpoint in HERE Maps Geocoding and Search API v7?

Tags: here-api

I'd like to limit the search radius for Reverse Geocode request in Geocoding and Search API v7, but the [official documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoding-search-api/api-reference-swagger.html) only describes three parameters: at, limit and lang, none of which serves that purpose. My intuition was that I could maybe use 'in' instead of 'at' like this:
`in=circle:55.1,45.7;r=15` where 15 would be the radius in meters, but it results in an error saying that the 'at' parameter is required. Indeed, so says the documentation too. But how do I specify the search radius then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "in maintenance" previous version of Reverse Geocode still works fine and I'd suggest using it for now: https://developer.here.com/documentation/geocoder/dev_guide/topics/resource-reverse-geocode.html.